# Android: How to change the status bar color in JellyBean (API 18)

Tags: android, statusbar

I want to implement transparent/colored status bar in Android JellyBean (v18). After reading lots and lots of SO threads and googling, I decided to post a new question.

I have seen an app in my JellyBean phone which does this. (Asus Email app)

### **Screenshot 1 (sidebar collapsed**

[image]

### **Screenshot 2**

[image]

### **Screenshot 3**

[image]

I know it can be done in API > KITKAT. But I want to understand how to do similar effect in API > 16. I am using **v7** support library and **AppCompatActivity**. I have also tried below code

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white100</item>
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>
```

I have no clues now. Please help!

Comment: Did you find any solution? Because I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry posting this as an answer but I can't comment yet. Android doesn't have this implemented on it's API before kitkat. So I think that you're using a smartphone from asus and the app in the screenshots is a native app. In this case asus could do it by changing the android source code.

Comment: can you please post the reference of your answer that this property is not available in the versions of android < API 21 ?